# Why companies ask for feedback on recruitment process but do not provide feedback when rejecting?

Tags: hiring-process

I noticed a lot of companies exhibit the following behavior:

They reject an application with a generic response such as "We decided not to go ahead but we won't provide any reasons as to why we did so because .". This is obviously a bogus response, they already know the reasons, just don't want to share it.

A few days later they ask for feedback on the recruitment process.

Why do companies expect candidates to provide feedback when they themselves do not give feedback to the candidates?

Comment: I'd provide just one piece of feedback on the recruitment process, "Please share the reasons for a refusal" and move on.

Comment: Was the request for feedback just a generic survey or did it come from an actual human being that was involved in the recruitment process?

Comment: @Hilmar I have encountered both generic surveys and humans asking for feedback. In fact, most of the times it is a human asking.

Comment: **Why do companies expect candidates to provide feedback when they themselves do not give feedback to the candidates?** - They don't expect you to, they asked you to. Who knows why. Every company is different. If you don't want to provide feedback then don't.

Comment: It's the Golden Rule: he who has the gold makes the rules.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why do companies expect candidates to provide feedback when they themselves do not give feedback to the candidates?

The short, clumsy, and "not-so-helpful" answer would be "**Because they can**" and because there is no labor law against that. This is also the correct answer in many countries.

It may be unfair to you, and you can decline to provide feedbacks to the companies if you wish. They can't force you to provide your feedback to them.

---

The more elaborated answer would be:

1. If the companies give some reasons for rejections, that may lead to
   more questions and explanations from the rejected candidates to the hiring managers
   who reject them. That could also potentially lead to some lawsuits
   for a variety of reasons (whether the reasons are justifiable or
   not may be debatable.)
2. But, if the companies can get the feedback from candidates about the
   recruitment or interview process, that could help the companies to
   improve their hiring process in the future.

Again, as I mentioned above, this may sound unfair to some candidates, and the candidates can decline to provide the feedback because the feedback is optional.

Comment: ditto this, the same thing goes for asking for the reason the company rejected you. You CAN ask because you CAN, they can also choose to refuse to answer you whether it is because its their policy or whatever. Many people mistake common customs for physical impediments, they are not. Asking for the impossible is always POSSIBLE. Sometimes you may even get it.

Answer (score 3):

> Why do companies expect candidates to provide feedback when they themselves do not give feedback to the candidates?

Because the laws are made this way. Giving feedback "wrongly" as the company can bring down a multi-million dollar lawsuit. But there is nothing short of threatening violence that would have any legal consequences in the feedback of the applicant.

See: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99484/is-there-any-chance-i-could-get-in-legal-trouble-if-i-respond-to-a-job-rejection

As a thought experiment, what would happen if a company wrote "sorry, we don't employ disabled jewish black women over 50" (did I miss a protected class?)? That would be a legal nightmare. What would happen if an applicant would say "sorry, I don't work for disabled jewish black women over 50"? Well, nothing. As a private person, such laws don't apply to them. A private person has every right to be an idiot.

I wouldn't say they *expect* feedback though. They ask nicely. And why not. Worst case they get ghosted. Nothing to lose really.

Comment: Still does not stop a rejected candidate from asking for feedback also. Even if the chances are nil to impossible, one might actually give it. I just wouldn't expect it for the reason you gave or any reason for that matter.

Comment: @RanaldFong I've interviewed for one of the big tech companies a while ago and they were happy to provide feedback afterwards. It's worth asking - even if they didn't hire you they might want you to apply for a different position or at a later time.

Comment: You could offer to improve their feedback gathering process and they might hire you.